# Legend issues when mapping plot to FacetGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, line-plot, relplot

I've also opened an issue in the seaborn git repo [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2916). However, instead of a bug, it's quite possible that instead I'm making some basic error - but I haven't figured it out yet...

**Question:**
The same color is assigned to two different values in the legend. How to prevent this from happening as I scale up to more graphs that only contain a subset of the values assigned to the 'hue'?

**The code to reproduce:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


sna = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x' : np.tile(range(10), 5), 
        'y' : list(range(10)) + list(range(2,12)) + list(range(4, 14)) + list(range(6, 16)) + list(range(8, 18)),
        'id_for_hue' : ['foo']*10 + ['bar']*10 + ['baz']*10 + ['bar']*10 + ['baz']*10,
        'id_for_graph' : ['a']*30 + ['b']*20
    }                                
)

g = sns.FacetGrid(sna, col='id_for_graph')
g.map_dataframe(
    sns.lineplot,
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    hue = 'id_for_hue'
)

g.add_legend()
```

[image]

On the other hand, if I sort so that the values from the second plot appear at the top of the dataframe, the problem is resolved.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(sna.sort_values(['id_for_hue']), col='id_for_graph')
g.map_dataframe(
    sns.lineplot,
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    hue = 'id_for_hue'
)

g.add_legend()
```

[image]

**Versions:**

- seaborn: 0.11.2
- matplotlib: 3.5.2
- pandas: 1.3.4
- numpy: 1.21.6
- python: 3.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe unsurprisingly, I should have read the documentation more closely. As mentioned in the [lineplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) documentation "Using [relplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot) is safer than using [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) directly, as it ensures synchronization of the semantic mappings across facets". In fact, in the [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) documentation it's pointed out that "in most cases you will want to use figure-level functions (e.g. displot(), relplot()) to make the plots".

So, use relplot(). e.g.

```
sns.relplot(
    data = sna,
    col = 'id_for_graph',
    kind = 'line',
    x = 'x',
    y = 'y',
    hue = 'id_for_hue'
)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Some additional information from mwaskom that might be helpful for others:

> yes, this is exactly the kind of situation that the warning in the FacetGrid docstring is about:
>
> [image]
>
> `relplot` is the recommended approach here; if you really needed to make your plot by initializing the facet grid (and couldn't just tweak the object that `relplot` returns), you would have a few options:
>
> - set a categorical dtype on your `hue` variable
> - pass `hue_order` to `lineplot`
> - pass a dict of colors to `palette`